# android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.android.chrome

Tags: android, android-studio, google-chrome

I'm not able to fetch package info of google chrome app only in android 11 devices / API 30. Rest all devices working fine

Please check the below code mentioned.

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        pi = pm.getPackageInfo("com.android.chrome", 0);
        value = pi.versionName;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.toString()
    }
```

Exception Thrown : android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.android.chrome

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Problem Solved..
Introduction to Android 11, Google updated Security policy to access packages selectively and individually instead of fetching all packages.

For this need to add  element in manifest.

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9

```
 <manifest package="com.example.game">
   <queries>
      <package android:name="com.example.store" />
      <package android:name="com.example.service" />
    </queries>
 </manifest>
```