# Exception: Android.Content.PM.PackageManager+NameNotFoundException: ComponentInfo{com.company.product/parse.ParsePushService}

Tags: parsing, xamarin.forms, parse-platform, push-notification, xamarin.android

I'm using the Parse sdk (Parse.Android.dll) & When i intialize the parse sdk like this

```
ParseClient.Initialize(new ParseClient.Configuration
                {
                    ApplicationId = AppName,
                    Server = ServerAddress + "/parse"
                });
```

I gets the error like

```
Exception: Android.Content.PM.PackageManager+NameNotFoundException: ComponentInfo{com.company.product/parse.ParsePushService}
```

I know the similar was asked over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64819384/android-content-pm-packagemanagernamenotfoundexception-com-android-chrome) but i already have it in place & it doesn't help. And the same is reported on github with no solution https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-dotNET/issues/167

Manifest

```
<queries>
      <package android:name="com.company.product" />
</queries>
```

Does anyone knows any work around for this? As have already spend a week to figure out whats wrong within this.

Note: It just throws the exception when System.Execptions are enabled. But it works well.

Just wants to know, if everything is working fine then why is it throwing the exception?